# writng switch statement of an already made if-else statement in php

Tags: php

i amjust startingout in php, i wanted to know how we write the `switch` equivalent of the following `if..else` statement:

```
$op1 = array("12", "13", "14");
$op2 = array("15", "16", "17", "18");
//echo $op1[1];
if(count($op1)> count($op2)){
echo "wrong";
}
else{
echo "right";
}
//ouptput is "right"
```

i tried the switch in this, but got it all wrong. i tried this and it gave a huge error:

```
   //switch for the if-else


 switch (count($op1)>count($op2)){
case (false):
echo "it is false";

case (true):
echo "it is true";
```

in the output, both "it is true" and it is flase" are showing.

please give the right way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Why you need `foreach` for that?

Comment: I believe he means "switch-case"

Comment: Why you need switch case?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What output do u want and what actually do you want to compare?

Comment: [Just read the documentation on switch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). Don't waste our time asking questions you could trivially google. Also, proofread your questions to see if they make sense, and don't ask a question at a time you're going to run off for 11 hours because people might ask for clarification about what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach is used as in case of loop statement. I din find any loop hear.

If you have to get one by one all the values of the array you can use foreach.

foreach($array_val ad $val){
   //you can use $val hear..

}

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```
// Use switch for the if-else

switch (count($op1)>count($op2)) {
    case FALSE:
        echo "it is false";
        break;

    case TRUE:
        echo "it is true";
        break;

    // default:
        // default is not required here, as the result is either TRUE or FALSE
}
```

Comment: i am sorry to you all, i meant switch, not foreach. Can anyone give me the switch equivalent of the if..else statement i mentioned in the question? Again, i apologize for the mistake.

Comment: In your first code you are comparing the count of elements in the array and in the switch statement you are directly using arrays to compare.Please edit the question to make it sound and clear.

Comment: this is the switch statement for which i was needing a better code, as it is not working. what is happening is that both cases are showing in output. i have updated the code in the question. i think there is problem in the  "case(true)" and "case(false)" statements

Comment: @user3450590 When you edited it you removed the `break;` statements.  This really isn't difficult. If you'd just [read the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) you'd get it.

Comment: Why are both your cases false? Shouldn't there be different cases? Otherwise only the first will only ever run.